# Creating dom elements with jquery - performance difference?

Tags: jquery

I really dont like writing something like

```
$('body').append('<div class="foo">foo</div>');
```

Because i usually end up with a quite messy string.

I prefer doing something like

```
var $div = $('<div/>').attr({ 'class' : 'foo' }).text('foo');
$('body').append($div);
```

Someone told me that the last option is a lot slower, performance-wise. So i would like some input from you guys. Is there a difference? Which way do you prefer?

Thanks

Comment: I suspect the second way is slower as it's doing three times the work, but why not just run 1,000 iterations of each and time them? Also, personally, I think the first method is far easier to read.

Comment: The second one less messy than the first one O_o...?

Comment: @RobW It depends on how you look at it. I prefer controlling the attributes with methods instead of writing a long string. But thats just me. Thanks for the answers

Comment: @Johan You can split up a string, '<div class="foo">' +` *linebreak* `'foo' + ` *linebreak* `'</div>';`. That is still readable, and not affecting performance. Instead of direct string concatenations, you can make it look even better by using arrays, with the [`.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) method. Especially when you're dealing with complex structures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second method is very noticably slower in most web browsers.

Basically the first method can pass the string to .innerHTML and let the web browser do its thing in native code, whereas the second method has to invoke a lot of separate JS methods, each of which in turn calls some native function in the web browser to make an adjustment.

For a small example, such as that shown there is almost no noticable difference - but if you profile adding, say 1000 rows to a table using each method, you will notice a significant difference in time taken - particularly on the slower browsers.

In fact, using the second method with any significant amount of elements on IE 8 or lower tends to lock up the browser for some time.

Answer (score 1):

The second way seems a lot more cumbersome, I'd much rather do it the first way because of how neater it looks. Regarding performance, yes, the first is also faster.

If you have performance tests you need to check, use jsperf. I compared your 2 methods and the results are as expected, the second method is ~59% slower in Firefox: http://jsperf.com/creating-dom-elements

Comment: Your JSPerf is *slightly flawed* (the second method is even more faster than the first one!). You have to remove the appended elements after inserting them, because appending the elements in a big tree is slow. Here's the updated JSPerf, including a vanilla JavaScript method: http://jsperf.com/creating-dom-elements/2

Answer (score 0):

I think its slower because:

- you allocate space for a variable with $div
- 2 methods are being called at the point of initialization, and you don't know if those methods dont call or use further methods.
- appending is used in both methods but in the first method I guess its faster because you are adding pure text and in the second method what you are adding is a jquery Object which would also compute some cpu time again, but don't nail me down on this fact.

These are my thougts about that code.